# Absolute positioned div expands the page when it appears

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, absolute

I dont know the name of my question thus i created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2EMu/270/)

You see that i have `absolute positioned` divs which toggles when you click their ancestors. However if you click below div the page expands. I want it appear in a different place than others to prevent expanding. I am sure that i saw something like this before. If there is not enough space absolute positioned divs appear right of the ancestor else it appears left of the ancestor. How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: You need to compare the `offset().top + height` of the absolute divs to the `window.height`. If it's greater, set `bottom: 0` on the div.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan, I was going to say the same thing. You have to get the window's height and then compare it to the toggle'd div's height to make sure it won't over set.

Answer (score 0):

you have attached the event on the .relative div but its pareent div which hold the place of the child (absolute) div 
you need to try this after attaching the event
$('.absolute').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();

})